# Rectangle MouseDown throwing the Parent Canvas MouseDown Event in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I have a rectangle on a canvas:

```
<Canvas x:Name="CanvasMain" MouseDown="Canvas_OnMouseDown" Width="595" Height="842" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Rectangle Fill="Tomato" MouseDown="Rectangle_OnMouseDown" Height="335" Canvas.Left="145" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="225" Width="265"/>
</Canvas>
```

The problem is: when I click upon the rectangle, both the rectangle `MouseDown` and canvas `MouseDown` events are triggered. I want to work with only the rectangle `MouseDown` when I click on the rectangle and work with the canvas `MouseDown` when I click outside the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens due to [event bubbling](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464926/To-bubble-or-tunnel-basic-WPF-events).

> Bubbling happens when the event is not handled by the element (say a textbox) and the event "bubbles" its way up the UI containers which hold it.

You should set `.Handled = true` on the event in the `Rectangle_OnMouseDown` handler.